# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS') [async function handleKickCommand]

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')
> at handleKickCommand (/home/runner/VPL-BOT/index.js:246:45)
> at Client. (/home/runner/VPL-BOT/index.js:189:11)
> at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at Client.emit (node:domain:489:12)
> at InteractionCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/VPL-BOT/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
> at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (/home/runner/VPL-BOT/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
> at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/VPL-BOT/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:354:31)
> at WebSocketManager. (/home/runner/VPL-BOT/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:238:12)
> at WebSocketManager.emit (/home/runner/VPL-BOT/node_modules/@vladfrangu/async_event_emitter/dist/index.js:282:31)
> Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
> at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:394:10)

```
async function handleKickCommand(interaction) {
  const userOption = interaction.options.getUser("user");
  const reasonOption = interaction.options.getString("reason");

  if (!userOption) {
    return interaction.reply("Vui lòng chỉ định người dùng cần kick.");
  }

  const userToKick = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(userOption.id);

  if (!userToKick) {
    return interaction.reply("Không tìm thấy người dùng trong máy chủ.");
  }

  const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.user.id);
  if (!member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.KICK_MEMBERS)) {
    return interaction.reply('Bạn không có quyền thực hiện lệnh "kick".');
  }

  try {
    await userToKick.kick(reasonOption || "Không có lý do.");

    await interaction.reply(`Đã kick người dùng ${userToKick.user.tag}.`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    await interaction.reply('Đã xảy ra lỗi khi thực hiện lệnh "kick".');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error originates from the line where you check if the member has the permissions `'KICK_MEMBERS'` and is caused because `'Permissions'` is undefined. To check member permissions use

```
member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.KickMembers)
```

instead. If you want to check multiply permissions you can put them into an array within the `'has()'` function.

```
member.permissions.has([PermissionsBitField.Flags.KickMembers, PermissionsBitField.Flags.BanMembers])
```

For more information check the Discord.js guide about this topic [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#checking-member-permissions).